# Dynamically Generated HTML codes do not have jQuery attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of Div that is made draggable by using jquery.

```
        <div id="external-events">
        <h4>List Of Staffs</h4>
              <div class="external-event" data-id="1">Name</div> //Draggable
        </div>
```

This is the code that makes it draggable

```
        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()),
                id: $(this).data('id')
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });
```

So I have to implement it such that the Div is dynamic so I have added codes that generated it. It generated out correctly but it does not get the jQuery attributes such as the being draggable. Here is javascript codes:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/getListOfStaff",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                $("#external-events").html(msg.d);
            }
        });

        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()),
                id: $(this).data('id')
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });
```

I used firebug and checked the html generated, it is exactly the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Try putting your `each` method inside a function and call that function inside the Ajax success method.

Comment: thanks! works great, but will have to give it to andre

Answer (score 0):

It's because the $.ajax function is not synchronous by default. This means that after the $.ajax call, probably the request will not have completed yet, meaning that your `$("#external-events")` query will return 0 elements.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        function makeDraggable() {
            $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

                // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
                // it doesn't need to have a start or end
                var eventObject = {
                    title: $.trim($(this).text()),
                    id: $(this).data('id')
                };

                // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
                $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

                // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex: 999,
                    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                });

            });
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/getListOfStaff",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                $("#external-events").html(msg.d);
                makeDraggable();
            }
        });

});
```